# Easy way to convert mesh outline into texture paint map/image?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I’m looking for suggestions on how to easily (and relatively accurately) convert a mesh pattern into an image for texture painting.

I’m modeling non-existent Earth-like planets for a sci-fi project. To begin, I took an Ico Sphere and subdivided it. Then, in Geometry Nodes, I multiplied a Voronoi and Noise Texture together to use as a basis for adjusting the height/depth of the mesh relative to the original radius of the sphere. I then applied Shading depending on the height of the surface and adjusted various parameters. I adjusted the parameters further until I had something I liked. (See image: Version one.)

Next, I added another sphere about the same size as the first and did a Boolean operation to create a mesh that was all “landforms.” I painted the Boolean sphere blue (for ocean) and added some latitude and longitude stripes. Then I subdivided the land mass mesh into about 6 smaller meshes and rearranged some of them into a pattern that I really liked. (See image: Version two.)

So far, so good. It’s the next part that I haven’t thought of a good way to do.

What I want is to create a flat texture map (that I can wrap around a blank sphere) that preserves the shapes and positions of the land mass meshes that I currently have. (Just the outlines. I don’t need to preserve the elevation shading; that’s going to be edited anyway.)

Like, if this were a real object, I could spray paint the “ocean” sphere and then, when I removed the land masses, the paint pattern on the sphere would have holes where the land masses used to be, because the land mass meshes acted as masks. UV unwrapping the sphere would then provide a basis for the flat map I’m looking for.

Is there a way to convert the shapes of the meshes into masks for texture painting? I’m pretty sure if I tried texture painting the sphere surface right now the paint would pass right through the land mass meshes and put paint everywhere. I believe I can flatten the land meshes to match the diameter of the underlying sphere using the shrinkwrap modifier, but I still don’t know how to go from that to a working mask. (I’m thinking flattening the land meshes would be a necessary first step.)

I suppose I could also use a solidify modifier on the meshes and then another Boolean to put holes in the underlying sphere. If I UV unwrapped that, would it have holes in it.

I’m a total novice at texture painting and UV unwrapping, by the way.

[image: Version One of planet]

[image: Version Two of planet]

[image: Version Two no shading]

[image: B&W Texture Map]

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Is it what you would like to achieve : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I7a5.png ? The right hole is using a boolean modifier. The left cut is using Knife Project of a curve.

Comment: Could you just unwrap a simple sphere that would serve as a target for baking? Using AO pass probably to get white on the land masses and black outside that possibly.

Comment: StefLAncien: (1) Not sure that would add anything. (2) I've never done that before, so I'll have to figure out how. Maybe later. (3) The example you provided is not what I'm trying to do. Or at least, it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Craig D Jones: Sorry, most of your suggestion went right over my head. An image of an unwrapped simple sphere (say, 4000 pixels wide by 2000 pixels tall) is just what I want. What's an AO pass? How do I bake the file I currently have to get there?

Comment: Craig D Jones: Your suggestion was just what I was looking for. THANKS! I had to look up AO burning, but once I figured out how that worked (more or less), it gave me pretty much exactly what I was looking for.